# Understand the linux build process

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm trying to build the linux kernel and would like to understand a few things:

1. I have added a new file (b.c) to a certain directory with the intention of having the file compiled in. The Makefile has been updated accordingly. While compiling the file, an error is thrown saying that a certain header (a.h) is not found. However, other files in the same directory use a.h without any issues.
2. I have observed that .o.cmd file get created for all files except b.c. Is this a prerequisite for the headers to be correctly included? Does this file have any significance to the issue I'm facing?

For eg: I added 'async_infra.o' to this line in the Makefile:

```
uml_gre-objs := uml_gre_kern.o uml_gre_user.o async_infra.o
```

uml_gre_user.c includes the header that I'd like to be included in async_infra.c

Any suggestions on what's missing and how to address the issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Show us how you updated the Makefile to include the new file.

Comment: Yes, we need additional information. Be more specific, give examples of your changes.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: I added 'async_infra.o' to this line in Makefile: uml_gre-objs := uml_gre_kern.o uml_gre_user.o async_infra.o. The file uml_gre_user.c includes the header that I'd like to include in async_infra.c

Comment: @Maddy: please edit your question and include any useful information there; this will make it easier for future visitors to see whether it is useful for them

Comment: What exactly is the message? Is the compiler complaining about the missing header, or is make complaining? It's unclear from the question. In addition to showing the makefile entry, showing the `#include`(s) in your `b.c` file would help as well.

Comment: Read the documentation. [Kbuild documentation](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kbuild) and run `info make`; you need to understand **Gnu Make** if you want to understand all the details.  Especially note that `make V=1` will show the command lines and you can see include paths, etc.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their suggestions. After reading the build documentation, I learned that there are restrictions on which headers can be included in the kernel and user sources. This understanding enabled me to resolve the issue.